# Apache mpm event not working as expected with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, mpm-event

I have a server with `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)` + `OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips` (I know this is an old version of Apache but it cannot be upgraded right now). mpm event is used for multi processing.

When serving `HTTP` content, everything works as expected :

[image]

The server can handle many requests concurrently without trouble (the test was made with approximately 150 clients, each creating 4 parallel connections = 600 connections). All requests target static content and use keepalive.

with `HTTPS/SSL`, it's a different story.

[image]

It will quicky use all 400 possible threads (see scoreboard). No async connections will be made. AFAIK it behaves like `mpm worker`.

At first I thought it was a limitation and that `mpm event` would work only with HTTP. But this is not what is written in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/event.html) (under *How it Works* > *Async connections*) :

> These improvements are valid for both HTTP/HTTPS connections.

EDIT: there is some information in *Limitations* section of [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/event.html) that explain that in some case it might fall back to `mpm worker`. However it does not seems to apply here.

Comment: Do you KNOW that whatever client you are using for testing will use keep-alives over HTTPS? Are Keep-alives configured on SSL vhost? Are you using the config from Ralph Engeshall's Howto (last updated 2001 which disables Keepalives for some ancient browsers)

Comment: I use an C# console app to simulate workload, which use HttpClient class with default settings (I did not change keepalive).

Comment: Does not answer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking at Apache source code for possible `mpm worker` fallback conditions, I found the following relevant [comment](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/mpm/event/event.c#L1117) :

> If we have an input filter which 'clogs' the input stream, like
> mod_ssl used to, lets just do the normal read from input filters, like
> the Worker MPM does.

Since I am using an old version of Apache that could be explain `mpm event` not working well with SSL.

EDIT: it looks like this has been done in this [commit](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/a47569f7c178f01494b78af9df82c55642fb6b17) :

> core, mod_ssl: Lift the restriction that prevents mod_ssl taking full advantage of the event MPM.

I use Apache `2.4.6` and change has been released later, in `2.4.7`.